Detect timestamp changes in React Native
We are currently developing an attendance management application and the core functionality is for the user to check in and check out through the app even when they're offline.
The problem we're facing right now is of the timestamp. User can change their device time and that changed time is reflected on the app manipulating the core purpose of the app. According to my research I don't think we can prevent it, just looking for ideas that how can we solve this problem or if is there any work around you guys can think of.
Thanks
